# UnitOfWork and Repository pattern - find in-memory objects

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I am using UnitOfWork and Repository pattern.

```
// generic repository
public class Repository<T> : where T : class
{
    private readonly DbSet<T> _dbSet;

    public Repository(DbSet<T> dbSet)
    {
        this._dbSet = dbSet;
    }

    public IQueryable<T> Queryable()
    {
        return this._dbSet.AsQueryable();
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> All()
    {
        return this._dbSet.AsEnumerable();
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where)
    {
        return this._dbSet.Where(where);
    }

    public T First(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where)
    {
        return this._dbSet.First(where);
    }

    public T FirstOrDefault(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where)
    {
        return this._dbSet.FirstOrDefault(where);
    }

    public void Add(T entity)
    {
        this._dbSet.Add(entity);
    }

    public void Delete(T entity)
    {
        this._dbSet.Remove(entity);
    }

    public void Attach(T entity)
    {
        this._dbSet.Attach(entity);
    }
}

// product repository
public class ProductRepository : Repository<Product>
{
    public ProductRepository(DbSet<Product> dbSet) : base(dbSet)
    {
    }
}

// unit of work
public interface IUnitOfWork
{
    ProductRepository ProductsRepository { get; }
    void Commit();
}

// DbContext as unit of work
public class ApplicationUnitOfWork : DbContext, IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly ProductRepository _productsRepository;

    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUnitOfWork()
    {
        _productsRepository = new ProductRepository(Products);
    }

    #region IUnitOfWork Implementation

    public ProductRepository ProductsRepository
    {
        get { return _productsRepository; }
    }

    public void Commit()
    {
        this.SaveChanges();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

When i want to insert a product in the DB, i do something like this:

```
_unitOfWork.ProductsRepository.Add(new Product());
_unitOfWork.Commit();
```

This works.

My problem is that, if i insert a product in the repository, and then try to retrieve it before calling `.Commit()`, the repository returns `null`.

```
Product product = new Product { Id = 5 };
_unitOfWork.ProductsRepository.Add(product);

Product theProduct = _unitOfWork.ProductsRepository.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == 5);
// theProduct is null
```

How can i change the Repository pattern implementation (or UnitOfWork) so it returns the "in-memory" objects also?

Comment: have you try to use Find instead of FirstOrDefault ? Otherwise you can query Set<Product>.Local.

Comment: +1 for `DbSet<T>.Find(params Object[])`

Comment: Ekkkk code smells everywhere.

Comment: @Phill: what do you mean?

Comment: BaseRepository is an antipattern, you make assumptions about how you get data, not all data has get by id, a composite type will never use a key by id, some things will never has a list, etc. But you're forcing that implementation.

Comment: In addition your UoW has knowledge of the repositories, this is also bad, you should inject the UoW into the repository, right now every time you create a new repository you need to update your UoW. Thats bad.

Comment: @Phill: step 1 would be to create independent repositories for each entity type that i have, and including only the methods i need for that entity. step 2: how? UnitOfWork should retrieve the repositories by constructors? do you have a link where i can see an example of a good UnitOfWork implementation?

Comment: I don't know enough about EF, I use NHibernate, but like NH's Session, the EF DataContext and such is actually a UnitOfWork. The only reason you need to abstract this to your own UoW is if you want to add your own functionality that isn't packed in already. Then I would just inject the UoW into the repository. How you manage the commiting of the UoW comes down to what you're building, if you're building a website then you can hook into the pre/end request events to commit/rollback/dispose etc.

Comment: @Phill: Nobody forces anybody to use a base class for every repository. Use it where it fits.

Comment: @RaraituL: Repository pattern is an abstraction layer to make your code less complex and to abstract away the DB access. Exposing `IQueryable<T>` in a repository is so wrong. OR/M specific knowledge is force upon the users, hence using the pattern makes no sense.

Comment: @jqauffin: Ok, i understand. Basically i will create repository methods with the exact parameters i use in queries. `FirstOrDefault(Guid id);` `FirstOrDefault(Guid parent_Id, int position);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option#1**

Use `Find` method rather than `FirstOrDefault`. Have a look a [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj573936.aspx) to see how it works:

> The Find method on DbSet uses the primary key value to attempt to find
>   an entity tracked by the context. If the entity is not found in the
>   context then a query will be sent to the database to find the entity
>   there. Null is returned if the entity is not found in the context or
>   in the database. Find is different from using a query in two
>   significant ways: A round-trip to the database will only be made if
>   the entity with the given key is not found in the context. Find will
>   return entities that are in the Added state.

**Option#2**

Query local data. Have a look at [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592872.aspx).